# How can I parametrize this function to accept a function and TextIO.closeOut as input?

Tags: function, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

Is it possible to parametrize this aux function to accept both `TextIO.closeOut outstream` and `readFileList xs outstream n` as input? Or must I use that append function in TextIO to have a less ugly function body? Is it possible to match their types?

Both bodies are essentially the same, the only difference is the second return function in the NONE case.

```
    fun readFileList (x::xs) outstream n =
    case xs of
        [] => (let
              val instream = TextIO.openIn x
              val readline = TextIO.inputLine instream
              fun aux readline n =
                      case readline of
                          NONE => (TextIO.closeIn instream; TextIO.closeOut outstream)
                        | SOME s => (TextIO.output(outstream, (getLineWriteCode s n));
                                     aux (TextIO.inputLine instream) (n + 1))
              in
                  aux readline n
              end)
      | _ => (let
             val instream = TextIO.openIn x
             val readline = TextIO.inputLine instream
             fun aux readline n =
                 case readline of
                     NONE => (TextIO.closeIn instream; readFileList xs outstream n)
                   | SOME s => (TextIO.output(outstream, (getLineWriteCode s n));
                                aux (TextIO.inputLine instream) (n + 1))
            in
                aux readline n
            end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to use partial application. Dunno why it took so long to figure it out, but it works. The only thing I'm wondering is that anonymous lambda function. Can I put something like a wildcard in there or is it fine the way it is?

```
fun readFileList (x::xs) n outstream =  
    let
        val part = readFileList xs n
        val instream = TextIO.openIn x
        val readline = TextIO.inputLine instream
        fun aux readline n function =
            case readline of
                NONE => (TextIO.closeIn instream; function outstream)
              | SOME s => (TextIO.output(outstream, (getLineWriteCode s n));
                         aux (TextIO.inputLine instream) (n + 1) (fn s => ()))
    in
    case xs of
        [] => (aux readline n TextIO.closeOut)
      | _ => (aux readline n part)
    end
```